# WooCommerce product category pages with previous and next term links

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I want to customize WooCommerce category page (archive-product.php) to show current product category, but also I want to create Previous & Next links to previous and next category term links somewhere in the page.

I've tried a lot of solutions with no luck. I've manage to implement a code that take actual category ID, I've added +1 and -1 and I was able to create the links but the big issue is when 'next link' is on the last category that is not working, is not infinite loop for the links. I.E if I'm on cat page 6 that is last category I have, next one should be 1 and prev one should be 5 and if I'm on first category, prev one should be 6 and next one should be 2.

Please find below the piece of code I`m using and is working but not as I need:

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'product_cat';
$cate = get_queried_object();
$cateID = $cate->term_id;

$next_cateID = $cateID + 1;
$prev_cateID = $cateID - 1; 

$next_term_link = get_term_link( $next_cateID, $taxonomy );
$next_term = get_term( $next_cateID, $taxonomy );
$next_slug = $next_term->name;

$prev_term_link = get_term_link( $prev_cateID, $taxonomy );
$prev_term = get_term( $prev_cateID, $taxonomy );
$prev_slug = $prev_term->name;
?>

<p><a href="<?php echo $prev_term_link ?>"><?php echo $prev_slug; ?></a></p>
<p><a href="<?php echo $next_term_link ?>"><?php echo $next_slug; ?></a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

You just need to define your first and your last categories Ids. Then it will work as an infinite loop *(assuming that your product category terms are sequential)*:

```
<?php
if ( is_product_category() ) :
$taxonomy    = 'product_cat'; // WooCommerce product category taxonomy
$term_id     = get_queried_object_id(); // Current product category term Id

// Get first product category term Id
$query_args  = array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'hide_empty' => false, 'orderby' => 'term_id', 'number' => '1', 'fields' => 'ids');
$term_id_1st = get_terms($query_args);
$term_id_1st = reset($term_id_1st);

// Get last product category term Id
$query_args['order'] = 'DESC';
$term_id_end  = get_terms($query_args);
$term_id_end  = reset($term_id_end);

$next_term_id = $term_id_end == $term_id ? $term_id_1st : $term_id + 1;
$prev_term_id = $term_id_1st == $term_id ? $term_id_end : $term_id - 1; 

$next_term_link = get_term_link( $next_term_id, $taxonomy );
$next_term      = get_term( $next_term_id, $taxonomy );

$prev_term_link = get_term_link( $prev_term_id, $taxonomy );
$prev_term      = get_term( $prev_term_id, $taxonomy );

?>
<p><a href="<?php echo $prev_term_link ?>"><?php echo $prev_term->name; ?></a></p>
<p><a href="<?php echo $next_term_link ?>"><?php echo $next_term->name; ?></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

To get the last category you can try the following

Comment: Thank you very much! I`m going to test it and let you know if is working.

Comment: Thank you very much! This can be an accepted answer. I've test it and is working very nice. Was wandering if there is an possibility to automatically search and define first and last category. I'm asking this because if I`m adding more categories the above code will not work property.

Comment: your code works perfect! This is definitely the accepted answer. Really hope your code will help other people too.

Comment: @DumitruGabriel Not sure as taxonomy terms doesn't follow each other (they are not sequential). So to make that suitable for everyone, it should be done in another more complicated way.